# How do I choose the learning rate and initial step size based on dataset size & number of categories?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, object-detection

I was looking at the configs in the tensorflow object detection model zoo ([link here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md)) and I noticed some differences with learning rate and step size based on dataset - which do make sense to me, but I wanted to perhaps get some feedback on any established guidelines for choosing these values.

In the faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco, the initial learning rate is .0003 and the initial step size is 900k iterations.  The coco dataset has 90 categories

In the faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_oid - the initial learning rate is .00005 and the initial step size is 6 million iterations.  This dataset has 545 categories.

Is there some guideline for how many epochs you need to train at the initial learning rate?  Does it relate more to the size (number of total images) of the dataset? Or does it relate more to the number of categories?

Comment: It is a research question. No definitive answer yet, gazillion approaches available. Keywords for googling: "learning rate schedule", "hyperparameter search". Here is one example (grid search): assemble a list of "meaningful" learning rates and steps, train the model from scratch for every combination, pick the one that performs best on validation set, do cross-validation. Another example: pick an initial learning rate, train until validation metrics stops improving; decrease learning rate by some factor; go until validation metrics stops improving, etc. Many more stuff on gscholar and arxiv.

Comment: I tried googling this but wasn't able to find info on epochs to train before the learning rate drops.  Does the learning depend more on the model or more on the dataset or both?  I was surprised to see that the learning rate is different for the same model because the dataset is different

Comment: So if you google "learning rate schedule" you will find a lot of publications, articles, opinions, meaning that there is no consensus whatsoever. The choice is defined by both data and model and many more factors, like optimization algorithm, desired target metrics value, amount of compute available, development phase etc. The exact numbers for the models you are referring to are likely chosen empirically and quite randomly. Don't look for too much wisdom in it. There could be (and probably are) parameters and strategies that work even better than those.